# Why I can't get a tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I know there are this kind of questions here a lot already.
But I've not been able to fix my problem with those QnA.

Please see the [picture] that explains my situation first.
==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCeY2.jpg

My ultimate goal is to get the value in red-rectangle-1.
So I tried to read the tag in red-rectangle-2 in red-rectangle-3 with Beautiful Soup. But I couldn't.
Actually I couldn't get any tag in red rectangle-2.

Following is my code. What's the problem? What am I missing?

#

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from urllib.request import urlopen

res = urlopen('http://finance.naver.com/item/main.nhn?code=005490')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

#
# I can't find 'table' tag in red rectangle-2
tag0 = soup.find_all('table', {'class':'gHead03'})

i = 0
while i < tag0.__len__():
    print(tag0[i])
    i = i + 1
    print('\n', i)


# But I can find 'ul'tag out of red rectangle-2
tag1 = soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'tabs_submenu tab_total_submenu'})

i = 0
while i < tag1.__len__():
    print(tag1[i])
    i = i + 1
    print('\n', i)
######################################################################
```

Comment: Why is it that you use `'http://finance.naver.com/item/main.nhn?code=005490'` in your code, while on the image it's `http://finance.naver.com/item/coinfo.nhn?code=005490` opened?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source returned even using the correct url as per your image you won't see the table as it the html is  retrieved using a different url which you can see under the doc tab in chrome dev tools:

[image]

So all you need to do is pass the one param which is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {"cmp_cd":"005490"}
res = requests.get("http://companyinfo.stock.naver.com/v1/company/c1010001.aspx", params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
tag0 = soup.find('table', {'class':'gHead03'})

print(tag0)
```

The only reason  `soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'tabs_submenu tab_total_submenu'})` is because there are other *ul.tabs_submenu tab_total_submenu* tags on the page that are not inside the *ghead03* table, you are not actually pulling anything from that table.

If we run the code you can see we do get the table:

```
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: import requests

In [4]: params = {"cmp_cd":"005490"}

In [5]: res = requests.get("http://companyinfo.stock.naver.com/v1/company/c1010001.aspx", params=params)

In [6]: soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

In [7]: tag0 = soup.find('table', {'class':'gHead03'})

In [8]: print(tag0)
<table class="gHead03" ...............
```

I cannot post the full output as the chinese characters are getting flagged as spam but it is all there.